# Android Studio data binding error, cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-databinding

I have a perfectly working project. It didn't give any error or anything. But today I upgraded my Android Studio to 4.0 version and Gradle plugin version to 4.0.0. Then I changed my gradle file.

So I change it from this

```
viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

to this

```
buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
    }
```

I sync my project. But it gives "cannot resolve symbol" error with my databindings.

I have a xml named "activity_admin_screen.xml" so I have variable like this

```
private  ActivityAdminScreenBinding binding;
```

This was working perfectly but now it gives cannot resolve symbol error. I tried invalidate and restart a  few times. I deleted project from my computer and clone it from my github again as a new project. I tried to write another xml files. But none of them recognized. I tried to write a new xml named activity_admin_screen2.xml. When I tried to write is as ActivityAdminScreen2Binding Android Studio doesn't recognize it.

I tried to Rebuild my entire project this doesn't help either. Can anyone help me with it I can't run my project.

I didn't post any code because this code works with previous Android Studio version perfectly. After the update no code changed but it doesn't work. I made a research but everyone says there is no need to change bindings. They say Android studio should take care of it. Thanks in advance I am  open for any possible solution.

**Solution:**

I changed this

```
buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
    }
```

to this

```
buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

Now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For android studio 4.0, You should try with  **`viewBinding = true`**

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild`**.

Comment: Thank you very much. This project was too important for me. I didn't read it correctly. I copied it from Google docs from about new updates about gradle 4.0 databinding. I didn't changed it to viewBinding so it gives error. I am trying to fix it for like 2 hours. I didn't even think about the change it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add both:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}
```